# Python DBAPI cursor fetchmany in a generator is closed too early

Tags: python, sqlite, generator, python-db-api

```
import dbapi2
conn = dbapi2.connect("db", autocommit=True)

def fetch_generator():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for res in cursor.execute('select * from table'):
        yield res

def generator_1():
    for x in fetch_generator():
        yield x

def generator_2():
    for x in generator_1():
        yield x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in generator_2():
        print(x)
```

This throws an error at `for x in fetch_generator()`

Error: `dbapi2.InterfaceError: Attempted to use a closed cursor`

Why is the cursor closing with the chain of generators? Is is a scope issue and are context managers one solution? How do I keep the cursor from having `del` or `close` called on it automatically -- somewhere not sure when -- and keep it open.

Comment: This is neither valid Python nor valid SQL. When I fix the obvious errors (`sqlite3` instead of `dbapi2`, no `autocommit`, `cursor`, table name, test data), the generators work for me. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: moving the conn = dbapi2.connect to the inside of fetch_generator